# Call javascript function on passing through link

Tags: javascript, ajax, content-management-system

I have a CMS which loads articles using ajax. The article is loaded through a function with some parameters. What I need is: when someone clicks a certain link, it will redirect him to the target page AND launch the function on target page. Is it possible? To be concrete, I have function loadArticle(articleID). When I access the page, there is article list. When I launch function loadArticle, it hides div with article list and shows particular article. So I need some way to call it through link, like: `<a onArticlePageLoad="loadArticle(15)" href="./articles">Title</a>`

---

Example: on page.html I have a link which points to page2.html. On click, I need to load page2.html and execute function foo in page2.html

Comment: We need a little more information because it sounds like an `onload` event is all you're talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by ChristianF you ll need to have an identifier on your link. I have this function:

```
function hashtagExecute(hashtagstring,action){
if (location.hash==hashtagstring) {
action();
}
}
/*Gets: STRING -- Beggining with '#'
 *      FUNCTION -- The function to be executed if the above string is present in the url
```

Then on the link page2 with foo execution
and onload:

```
window.onload =function (){

hashtagExecute("#foo",foo());
hashtagExecute("#bar",bar());
... //as many different cases you want just remember to actually have those functions :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a function that executes on page2.html at the bottom of the body or onload.

Answer (score 0):

As people were already saying, you will need some sort of onload event on page2. But it sounds like you want that function being called to change depending on what link was clicked on page1.

Would something like this work:

page1:

```
<a href="page2?A">page2 case A</a>
<a href="page2?B">page2 case B</a>
```

page2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function foo(){
        var case = window.location.search;
        if (case == "A") {
           functionA();
        } else {
           functionB();
        }
    }
</script>
```